# Photos still on computer even though deleted

Tags: windows-10

I deleted 900 photos from Windows 10 Photos. Emptied Recycle Bin.  Went to File Explorer,
This PC, Pictures-----AND ALL THE PHOTOS WERE STILL THERE!  Now I have to click on 900
photos again, one by one?  WHAT?

Comment: Try deleting a couple of pictures again and see if they actually make it to the Recycle Bin. It's possible you don't have delete permission. I'm sure you know you can mass delete images, but I'm guessing you have to hand select which images to delete?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The *Recycle Bin* can hold a limited amount, so if you try to delete *too much*, it can be that nothing gets moved there. You have a few choices:

- Move only a few GB to the bin at a time.
- Increase the [size of the *Recycle Bin*](https://www.howtogeek.com/366395/how-to-change-recycle-bin-settings-on-windows-10/) temporarily (If too large, it might take up too much disk space).
- If you're *confident*, use <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Delete</kbd> to *permanently* delete the files without using the bin.

Also, *how* did you delete the photos in the first place? From *Explorer*? Using CMD? And *where* are the files? Are they stored in the Cloud (e.g., *OneDrive*), as well as on the PC?